# Ubuntu 11.04 windows XP dual boot problem

Tags: 11.04

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 direct from installation disk in a separate partition alongside an existing Windows XP installation. Ubuntu operates fine. I can see the old XP file system and the other network computer and access the internet. The problem is when the computer starts I get the boot selection list for Ubuntu or XP; but I am not allowed to select Windows XP (I cannot scroll down the list with tab or arrows keys).  This would be fine for me but the computer is used by other people who are only familiar with windows XP at the moment.

I have downloaded and run Boot Repair. [Here are the resulting data.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1082944/)

Comment: does the keyboard respond at all in grub screen? try pressing `e` while selector cursor in ubuntu

Comment: If you urgently need Windows, you can setup GRUB menu to make Windows the default system. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2 But be careful: as your keyboard is KO at GRUB menu, you can revert this operation only from a live-CD or live-USB.

Comment: You may want to try connecting another keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Connect another keyboard (need one which is compatible with BIOS).